# Stability index proof in Feller

Tags: probability-theory, induction

Feller proves in his second volume that the norming constant for a stable distribution is of the form: $a_n=n^{1/\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in(0,2]$ where $\alpha$ is the stability index.
The proof uses the trick of writing copies of sums of independent variables  in different ways. However, there's an induction proof which I struggle to understand. How can he conclude the following?

[...] whence $c_{rk}=c_rc_k$ for all r and k. For subscripts of the $n=r^v$ we conclude by induction that
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad if\quad  n=r^v \quad then \quad  c_n=c_r^v$

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about this step...? $$c_{r^v} = c_{r^{v-1} r} = c_r c_{r^{v-1}} = c_r c_{r^{v-2} r} = c_r^2 c_{r^{v-2}} = \ldots = c_r^v.$$

Comment: Oh..I didn't see that. Thank you that was exactly what I didn't grasp.

Comment: You are welcome.